# Perform ORDER BY before GROUP BY without Joins and Subselects

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm currently working on an ajax-based chatand I got a component called `conversation_list` which contains all available chats with the following information: `chat_partner_id`, `chat_partner_type` (some kind of user-classification), `chat_partner_name` and `last_text_message`. I've got the following query to get all the required informations:

```
SELECT message.chat_partner_id, message.chat_partner_type, message.message AS last_chat_message, IF(message.chat_partner_type = 'normal_user', normal_user.username, premium_user.username) AS chat_partner_name
FROM message, normal_user, premium_user
WHERE IF(message.chat_partner_type = 'normal_user', message.chat_partner_id = normal_user.id, message.chat_partner_id = premium_user.id)
AND message.chat_user_id = 123 AND message.user_type = 'premium_user'
GROUP BY chat_partner_name
ORDER BY message.message_date DESC
```

The result is correct with the exception of the last_text_message. The result is not showing the last message of a chat. I think it's because the rows are getting grouped right before the `ORDER BY`.

Is there a way to show the right last message without complicated Joins and Subselects? I already tried to use `MAX()` on `last_text_message` without success.

Comment: It's documented that [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) with non-aggregated columns will select values in a indeterminate fashion, and that `ORDER BY` doesn't affect it.

Comment: Okay, so what is the best way to get the desired result?

Comment: Well, I'm not offering an answer because your question already precludes the obvious way to actual *obtain* the result you're looking for - use a subqeury.

Comment: A (correlated) subselect

Comment: @Roland Ooh, I'd go for the uncorrelated version, every time.

Comment: @baumlol I'm sure you don't need separate tables for normal and premium users. That's just messy. Also, you're already using (implicit) JOINs!